# python function random cycling if statements

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm making a rock paper scissor game and have run into a problem with the `decisioncycle()`. What I'm trying to do is ask the user to input a choice in `usercycle()`, have the computer generate a random choice in `gamecycle()`, then determine who won the round and keep track of each result with a win and loss count. It seems to be deciding when to work at random.

```
import random


class rpsgame:

    rps= ["rock", "paper","scissors"]


    wincount=0
    losecount=0
    def usercycle(self):
        userchoice = input("rock, paper, scissor.....")
        print("SHOOT")
        return userchoice

    def gamecycle(self):
        computerchoice = random.choice(rpsgame.rps)
        return computerchoice




    def decisioncycle(self):
            if rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[0] and rpsgame.gamecycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[1]:
                    print("paper beats rock, you lose!")
                    rpsgame.losecount +=1
            elif rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[1] and rpsgame.gamecycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[0]:
                    print("paper beats rock, you win!")
                    rpsgame.wincount+=1
            elif rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[0] and rpsgame.gamecycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[2]:
                    print("rock beats scissors, you win!")
                    rpsgame.wincount+=1
            elif rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[2] and rpsgame.gamecycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[0]:
                    print("rock beats scissors, you lose!")
                    rpsgame.losecount+=1
            elif rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[1] and rpsgame.gamecycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[2]:
                    print("scissors beats paper, you lose!")
                    rpsgame.losecount+=1
            elif rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[2] and rpsgame.gamecycle(self) == rpsgame.rps[1]:
                    print("scissors beats paper, you win!")
                    rpsgame.wincount+=1
            elif rpsgame.usercycle(self) == rpsgame.gamecycle(self):
                    print("it's a tie!!!")
            print("wins {}, losses {}".format(rpsgame.wincount, rpsgame.losecount))




while True:
    rg = rpsgame()
    rg.usercycle()
    rg.gamecycle()
    rg.decisioncycle()
```

I think my problem is in the decisioncycle(). this is my first shot at a class as the game was working with global variables, but I read here that that is a bad practice to carry out for the future.

Comment: In decisioncycle, each if/elif statement is like a separate round of the game, which I don't think is what you really want.

Comment: Exactly, when I wrote it out like this without a class using global variables it worked as intended. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: In whatever function determines the outcome of the game, you should only call usercycle and gamecycle _once_, and assign the results to 2 variables.  Then use those variables to make comparisons.

Comment: The fact that this worked but I still dont fully understand why it worked in the first place with global variables is a lesson in itself. I should probably stay away from globals...

Comment: I actually understand now. The variable solution worked and it looks far cleaner too so thank you!! Your solution helped to me to understand where the mistake was.  If I still wanted to do it my long and tedious way without variables, could changing each function call instead to, .computerchoice and .userchoice, that would have fixed it too correct?

Comment: No, because computerchoice and userchoice are local to the gamecycle and usercycle functions.  They don't exist outside of those functions.  If you wanted them to be attributes of rpsgame, you'd have to prepend _self_ to them, e.g. `self.computerchoice`.

Comment: thats what I meant yes! that makes sense now. the functions in each if were definitely the problem

Answer (score 3):

instead of evaluating each combination using numerous cycles you can use modular arithmetic.

lets say that you make mapping

```
"rock" => 0
"paper"=>1
"scissors" => 2
```

you can evaluate solution as

```
(A.number - B.number) % 3
```

if this result is 0, it is draw, if it is 1 that A won if 2 A is lost

Comment: Could be a good use of enums, though it's not immediately obvious how that algorithm works. In all the RPS games I've seen on here I've never seen the arithmetic approach offered! I mean it's really cool it if works in all cases, though. Is it extensible? (Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock, for instance)

Comment: If you think of A-B  as difference you can see this as difference that is either -1,0 or 1 or when in finite field 0,1, and 2 (2 is same as -1). It is called arithmetic in finite filed and comes from number theory. In C for example % doesn’t work that way ad one should write this as (3+A-B)%3

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a new user input in each condition.  You probably want to read it just once and then compare it each time like

```
user_choice = self.usercicle()
game_choice = self.gamecycle()
if(user_choice == self.rps[0] and game_choice == self.rps[1]):
    print "Paper beats rock, you lose!"
    self.losecount += 1
elif( user_choice...
```

and so forth

Comment: Looking at this the difference I notice is you're running the two previous functions within a third, then just calling the third function to run the whole script. It's a cleaner way to do it but I tried this and it gave me the same result.

Comment: I was more suggesting an alternate way to implement the body of `decisioncycle`.  If nothing else, you could print at the top what the two choices are and try to figure which pairs of answers work or do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make a separate function for determining the winner, and use a dict, rather than a 7-way *if* statement:

```
def who_won(player, computer):
    rules = {"rock": "scissors", "paper": "rock", "scissors": "paper"}
    if player == computer:
        return None
    if rules[computer] == player:
        return "computer"
    return "player"
```

It's probably a good idea to check for invalid input, but that should be done in the input function, rather than this function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could actually be simplified. There are some mistakes, and they look like they are due to a simple unfamiliarity with classes. Take a look here:

```
class RpsGame:

    # create a game loop. Let's try a while loop
    # also, let's try using a dict to make comparisons easier

    def play(self):
        rps = {'rock':'scissors', 'paper':'rock', 'scissors':'paper'}
        score = 0
        # lets just say player must win 3 or lose 3 to end the game
        while -3 < score < 3:
            # ask user for their choice just once here, for instance
            user = raw_input("Rock, paper or scissors: ").lower()
            # and check the input is valid
            # get the computer choice with random

            # then find the winner and adjust score
            # when score reaches -3, computer wins etc.
            # comparisons could go like:
            if com == rps[user]: 
                score += 1
            elif user == rps[com]:
                score -= 1

        self.game_over(score)

    def game_over(self, score):
        if score == -3:
            result == "You win"
        else:
            result == "You lose"

        print "%s!!" % result


# We would start by instantiating the game
game = RpsGame()
# And then calling the play method
game.play()
```

I would go and have more of a read about classes and the usage of 'self' if I were you also.

Comment: Note that `self` is not a keyword! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of funky things there, but I think the problem you're having is that you're passing `self` to a function that doesn't (really) take an argument as input.

```
class TestClass(object):
    def some_method(self):
        return random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    def make_choice(self):
        return self.some_method(self)
        # raises TypeError
```

A method's classes are AUTOMATICALLY given the instance it belongs to as the first argument. If you try and pass that again, it fails.

That said, I think your class should look something like:

```
class Roshambo(object):
    ROCK = 'rock'
    PAPER = 'paper'
    SCISSORS = 'scissors'

    OPTIONS = [ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS]

    def get_user_input(self):
        choice = input("r/p/s? ").lower()
        if choice.startswith('r'): choice = self.ROCK
        elif choice.startswith('p'): choice = self.PAPER
        elif choice.startswith('s'): choice = self.SCISSORS
        else:
            # what do we do now?
            pass  # for now
        return choice

    def get_computer_input(self):
        return random.choice(self.OPTIONS)

    def start(self):
        # get input ONCE...
        user_choice = get_user_input()
        computer_choice = get_computer_input()

        if user_choice == ROCK and computer_choice == ROCK:
            # tie
        # etc....
```

Then instantiate

```
game = Roshambo()
```

And run

```
game.start()
```

Comment: All of his calls inside `decisioncycle` with `self` are perfectly valid - he's not calling them on an instance but on the class directly.

Comment: Admittedly he shoudn't be calling it at all there, but the way he's calling it definitely isn't his problem!

Comment: @Ben Hmm well I *did* miss that he's essentially calling `self.__class__.methodname(self)`, but even if that's not causing the error, it's definitely not helping things either!!